# Set Xamarin Forms custom renderer control to android resource xml

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

I am trying to get a material search bar working on a Xamarin.Forms project, but the native one is not good enough (talking about the looks). I've found this package https://github.com/FANMixco/Xamarin-SearchBar which is exactly what I need but I have no idea how to link the android resource xml for this search bar, to the actual view. I am familiar with custom renderers, but I can't seem to find a way to override the control and set the layout to the xml resource. I know how to set the style this way, but not the whole control.

If anyone knows anything I would be grateful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetNativeControl` method.

Usage:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SomeXamarinElement> e)
    { 
         base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // If element is being removed from view.
        if (e.NewElement == null)
            return;

         ...
         SetNativeControl(...);
    }
```

where `...` is inflating and using the native control. Replace `SomeXamarinElement` with the name of the Class this renderer is for.

Search for Xamarin.Android docs or tutorials to learn how to inflate an Android control with a specific XML.

(In an Android custom renderer, you are writing Xamarin.Android code. This is like writing a native app in java, except its in c#, with different naming conventions. So its also possible to learn the concepts by studying material written for Android development that is not using Xamarin.)